# How to literally translate this: 盖锅前须放进一些温水，预防糊底?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

接下来，拿一个平底锅，先在锅里淋一圈油，待油锅烫手时，将切好的萝卜饼一块一块地放进锅里。盖锅前须放进一些温水，预防糊底。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 19.

Please help me understand the literal translation of this: 盖锅前须放进一些温水，预防糊底。

I don't understand the 盖锅前须 and 糊：

盖锅前须(?)放进(to put in)一些(some or a little)温水(warm water)，预防(to prevent)糊(?)底(bottom)

盖：does it mean to cover?

锅：does it mean pan?

前：does it mean front?

须：does it mean must or have to?

Something like, you must cover the pan front? Or what else?

糊：rice gruel? To prevent rice gruel from bottom? I don't get the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

盖锅 = cover the pot (with lid)

前 = before

- 盖锅前 = before covering the pot

须 = need to

放进 = put in

一些 = some

温水 = warm water

- 须放进一些温水 = need to put in some warm water

预防 = to prevent

糊 = 燒焦 = burnt

底 = bottom (of the pot)

- 预防糊底 = to prevent burnt bottom (the food at the bottom that is in contact with the cooking surface)

> 盖锅前须放进一些温水，预防糊底

> need to put in some warm water before covering the pot, to prevent burnt (food) on the bottom

*I don't know why 焦 is called 糊, but it is how most Mandarin speakers say it. My guess is when food is burnt, it stuck together and 糊 also has the meaning of stuck together. 焦/糊底 = the bottom of the food burnt and stuck together, often stuck to the cooking surface too*

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. The Pleco dictionary says that a meaning of 糊 is: (of food) to be burnt.

Comment: I guess it's not most Mandarin speakers, but people when they are speaking Standard Mandarin.

Comment: I don't think it is typically used by "Mandarin speakers" I suppose 焦 is more towards the meaning of "burnt" which do not normally occur in cooking that's boiled and not fried or baked. So, 糊, (meaning turning into a sticky mess), is more appropriately used in relation to this type of liquid-based cooking.

Answer (score 2):

盖(cover)锅(pot/pan)前(before)须(should)放进(add/let in)一些(some)温水(warm water)，预防(to prevent)糊(scorching)底(the bottom).

The word-to-word translation obviously does not make a good sentence. Let's rephrase it as:

- Before covering the pot, (you) should add some warm water to prevent the (pot/pan) bottom from scorching.